# Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in E:\xampp\htdocs\berita\menuBerita.php on line 14

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and i am getting these errors:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in E:\xampp\htdocs\berita\menuBerita.php on line 14

Here is my code:

```
<?php
include "koneksi.php";
$ambil_recent = mysqli_query("select id_berita,judul,tanggal from tbl_berita order by rand() limit 20",$koneksi);

?>

<?php
while($hasil_recent= mysqli_fetch_array($ambil_recent)){
echo "<li><a href='index.php?link=lihatDetailBerita.php&id=$hasil_recent[id_berita]'>".$hasil_recent['judul']."</a></li>";
}
?>
```

Comment: I think Your `$ambil_recent` failed, giving null value

Comment: the syntax of `mysqli_query()` is wrong here please see below i have posted the answer for you.

Comment: @dboxcollection please up vote the answer too.. thn only others can easily refer the ans .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change the code

```
 <?php
    include "koneksi.php";// db connection $koneksi may you connection string or variable.
    $ambil_recent = mysqli_query($koneksi,"select id_berita,judul,tanggal from tbl_berita order by rand() limit 20");

    ?>
```

Please note the synatx `mysqli_query($connectionVar,$qry)`  You have made the mistake in passing the wrong parameter to the `mysqli_query` function.

Just change it and run your code . This will work

Answer (score 0):

You could use something similar to the below:

```
<?php
    $ambil_recent = mysqli_query($koneksi,"select id_berita,judul,tanggal from tbl_berita order by rand() limit 20");
    while($hasil_recent= mysqli_fetch_array($ambil_recent)) {  
       //do stuff
    }
?>
```